# toilet siphon has pressure beam of water

Tags: repair, toilet

I was wondering if it is normal that there is a pressure beam of water coming out from the toilet's siphon. And also, what I should do to fix this? I have the feeling this should not happen during 'normal operation'.

I tried tightening or losening the ring, but when I do, either the beam continues, or the beam stops, but still water is flowing into the toilet, even though the water reservoir is full.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, the water source should react on full/non-full condition. In your case, I'd try to disassemble the unit to make sure there is no rust/salt/etc preventing it to stop the water beam.

Then, about the beam itself. It depends on a water pressure and effective gate size, however it affects the fulfillment speed only. Once floating bobber is high enough, it pushes a lever that intends to shut the water gate.

Comment: Thanks, the water beam seems to be solved partly, meaning, after a flush, there is no water beam, however,  the toilet siphon doesn't stop when the water level has reached it's level. I cleaned it, and there was some dirt, but very little.

Comment: Does it stop the water if you pull the floating bobber up by hand?

Comment: No, instead the water beam starts, so the water level part seems to work, but still water gets out through a small hole (resulting in the water beam). Before the water level is reached, there is no beam, but the water goes down somewhere else (assuming that's the default way).

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this particular model of valve. Most toilet valves sold in the US have a soft "elastomer" seal which is available as an individual part. For those valves that is the only replaceable part that I know of. In the US an entire new valve assembly is fairly cheap and a common course of action is to replace the entire assembly rather than determining the exact failure point and trying to repair it.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. After some try, I found out it was easier to buy en entire system, which didn't cost much anyway. Thanks for the help/insights.

Comment: @JimStewart That's exactly what I did ... sorry for the late reply. Btw the toilet is fixed long time ago ;-)